# Can't find app in store without quotations around app name or remove space between names

Tags: android, google-play

I recently upload my app to the Google Play Store. I'm able to view my app in store by clicking from the developer's console. However, when I try to search the app myself by typing the name of the app it won't show up. I know this question has been raised many times, but I didn't really find a solution for this problem. The name of the app is called "Auto Reply Text Message".

I guess what I want to ask is that if it is possible to allow the user to find the app without putting the quotations around the name or removing all the spaces between?

Thank you in advanced.

Comment: How long has it been since you've published your app?

Comment: It has been 4 hours. I mean I can find my app in store if I search it with quotations, but not without it...

Comment: Just wait a couple of days

Comment: No..I have another app uploaded last month and also has the same issue. Can only be found with quotations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

so I called Google yesterday, and below are their response:

"
Thank you for your reply and your question about Google Play search.

When searching on Google Play, application search works across title, publisher and app descriptions. It's not easy to refine the search results appropriately when it comes to generic words that may also happen to be brand names or titles. For example, when a user searches for "Color Game", it's difficult to tell if the user is searching for an app named "Color Game" or for a game about colors. Because of this, we cannot guarantee that every app will display in search results for its name.

Please note, we show a limited number of search results in Google Play to ensure the best user experience. If your app's search rank for a specific term is too low, your app will not display in results. Keep in mind, however, that your app is always available by direct link (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=cle.app.auto.reply.text.message), which you can share with users as you actively market your app. You can also recommend users search for your app’s name in quotes (i.e. "app name") to have our search engine look for that exact combination of words.

Thank you for your understanding and continued support. If you have additional questions, please let me know.
"

So basically it has to do with their searching algorithm. I guess if your app has been downloaded for many times and becomes a popular app, Google will make your app a special case for searching and allow other people to search for your app without the quotations.

Thank you andrew for helping.

Comment: People can't find your app in search, they can't install it, so your app is never shows in "Top New Free", so you can't get any install... A few weeks later you can get 15/20 install daily... 
It's because of Google's search "algorithm". , I guess Google encourages us to work with AdMob.